# how to get rows between two string values in mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause, rows, between

My table looks like this:

```
id   city         road_id
-------------------------
1    london       3
2    manchester   3
3    newcastle    3
4    glasgow      3
5    london       5
6    newcastle    5
```

I know values of two cities and road_id and need something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET anothercolumn=1 WHERE id>=(id for)london AND id<(id for)glasgow AND road_id=3

to affect only these rows:
1    london       3
2    manchester   3
3    newcastle    3
```

Comment: So you want to select (in this case, for update) the rows with the id between id(London, inclusive) and id(Glasgow, exclusive)--rather than cities with names between "London" and "Glasgow"?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET anothercolumn = 1 
WHERE id >= (select id from your_table where city = 'london')
AND   id <  (select id from your_table where city = 'glasgow')
AND road_id = 3
```